# Python comprehension, dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I can't get my head around this one. Or am I over complicating things? I'm trying to make this code more 'Pythonic'.

```
statuses = {record['id'] : [] for record in data}

for record in data:
    for status in record['statuses']:
        data = {
            'status_code': status['statusCode'],
            'short_desc': status['statusShortDesc'],
        }

        if 'statusLongDesc' in status:
            data.update({'long_desc': status['statusLongDesc']})
        else:
            data.update({'long_desc': ''})

        statuses[record['id']] += [data]
    }
}
```

Several challenges here, code below I know is wrong but I'm trying to get across what I want with out knowing how:

- How do I update a list in a dictionary in a comprehension? Along the lines of this. Would this work? Something doesn't feel right about it to me. Have I got carried away with the curly brackets?

  ```
  statuses = {
      {
          record['id']: list({
              'status_code': status['statusCode'],
              'short_desc': status['statusShortDesc'],
              'long_desc': ''
          })
      }
      for record in data for status in record['statuses']
  }
  ```

This produces `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

- How can I then not repeat the data part like in my original code for adjusting long_desc? (My dictionary is actually a lot longer and it seems crazy to repeat it all for one line.) Like: `then if 'statusLongDesc' in status list.extend('long_desc': status['statusLongDesc'])` added to the above comprehension.

Comment: Your original code is far more "pythonic" IMO. It's very easy to read, and the intent is clear. Being pythonic means short, concise and easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't overcomplicate things. The biggest thing you can use to simplify your original is to use the `get` method.

```
statuses = {record['id']: [] for record in data}

for record in data:
    for status in record['statuses']:           
        statuses[record['id']].append({
            'status_code': status['statusCode'],
            'short_desc': status['statusShortDesc'],
            'long_desc': status.get('statusLongDesc', ''),
        })
```

Now, if you want, you can replace the loops with a dict comprehension that uses a list comprehension.

```
statuses = { record['id']: [{...} for status in record['statuses']] for record in data }
```

where `{...}` is the `data` dict in the original.

Comment: I find it weird, how he rebinds `data`, while iterating over it.

Comment: Good point. I'll get rid of the temporary name altogether in the answer, since it isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you. get method is a new one I won't forget. Handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create list using comprehension, instead of `.append`ing:

```
statuses = {}

for record in data:
    statuses[record['id']] = [
        {
            'status_code': status['statusCode'],
            'short_desc': status['statusShortDesc'],
            'long_desc': status.get('statusLongDesc', ''),
        } for status in record['statuses']
    ]
```

It can also be done in one expression this way, if I got nested comprehensions right:

```
statuses = {
    record['id']: [{
            'status_code': status['statusCode'],
            'short_desc': status['statusShortDesc'],
            'long_desc': status.get('statusLongDesc', ''),
        } for status in record['statuses']
    ] for record in data
}
```

But I find it unreadable.